# IQueryable<> Serialization - C#-VS2008-WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I built my *.dbml file with the required tables and that generated the relationships, 1 to many.

One of my methods in my WCF Service library has this query

```
 IQueryable<Client>localClient = from c in db.Clients
              where c.ClientID.Equals(2612)
              select c;

 foreach(Client currentClient in localClient)
 {
    //Call serialize method here
 }
```

One of the table which client has a 1 to many relationships is Client - Employee

With 'localClient', I want to serialize that and return to the invoker. However it tells me that the the XML document could not be formed.

This is the InnerException:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type TestDB_Public.Employee.

My serialization code

```
    public string Serialize(object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            if (ns != null)
                serializer.Serialize(m, o, ns);
            else
                serializer.Serialize(m, o);

            m.Position = 0;
            byte[] b = new byte[m.Length];
            m.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

            return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Ex = " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Is serialization of IQueryable<> with 1 to many relationships not possible?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason why you would need to have the collection type be IQueryable<>. Instead, use var and call the .ToList() method at the end of the query. Even if that doesn't work, it will make the point of actual query execution more explicit and clear

Comment: This comment was really helpful, Josh E. I implore you to flesh it out and resubmit it as an answer. Guaranteed upvote!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the error message? Note that you have to serialize something concrete like a list or array of objects (not a query).

If you want queryable over the wire, look at ADO.NET Data Services, which does this.

Also - have you set the serialization mode to "unidirectional" in the dbml designer? As long as there are no loops, it should work fine.

Comment: Marc:
This is the Innerexxception:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type TestDB_Public.Employee.

I do have set it to unidirectional. ADO.NET data service is a no go as the head honchos think it may not be secure enough

Comment: The circular reference is the loop I was afraid of - for example, if an employee can see their manager, and the manager can see their subordinates, it gets into a state. However, you can enable the graph serialization mode of DataContractSerializer: http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/02/wcf-cyclic-references-support.html or http://www.wearemappingyourdreams.com/andrew/ViewEntry.aspx?intLogId=1&intLogEntryId=622

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialise an object graph that has cyclical relationships:

```
class Employee
{
  Employee Manager;
  List<Employee> Employees;


}


var bossMan = new Employee();
var emp2 = new Employee{Manager = bossMan}
var bossMan.Employees.Add(emp2);
```

If you now try to serialise bossman or emp2, you will get the exception.

Have a look at [this post](http://broloco.blogspot.com/2009/02/sending-domain-objects-across-wire.html), check the Cyclic Object Graphs for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Marc:
For some reason it is not allowing me to add a comment;

I added this

```
[Table(Name="dbo.Client")]
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Client: INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ..//
  private EntitySet<ClEmp> _ClEmp;

  [Association(N...)]
  [DataMember(Order=70, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
  public EntitySet<ClEmp> ClEmps
}
```

My serialization is this:

```
DataContractSerializer ser =
                    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Client));
                var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                ser.WriteObject(ms, r);

                ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);



                var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ms);

                var xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

when i look at var xml, i do not get my enity set ClEmp.