# EntitySet serialization - WCF, C#, VS2008

Tags: c#, wcf

I asked this earlier and followed Marc's advise. That did not help me.

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831058/iqueryable-serialization-c-vs2008-wcf/831762#831762)

My client object is what I want to serialize but with Employee entity set, with any serialization, I get my object serialized without any reference to my EntitySets.

Anyone successfully serialized such objects?

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work out... can you clarify " without any reference to my EntitySets"? What *do* you get? Yesterday it was just erroring, so I'm unclear what the current state is.

Comment: Marc: What i mean is that when i look at my serialized object, my Employee element did not contain any value. I looked at the dbml.designer.cs file and noticed that my public EntitySet<ClEmp> ClEmps has this section
get
{
 if ((this.serializing && (this._ClEmp.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false))){return null;}
 return this._RegulationActions;
}

And it was always returning null even though _CLEmp.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues was always true. Upon removing the 'if' conditions, things seem to work but not sure why and also why that 'if' condition is placed by default code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info in the link, it looks like you are trying to serialise an IQueryable object.

I don't think that this is possible, it looses it's meaning when it goes out of scope of the db connection. Which it will when you go over a WCF hop.

What you can do is to pull the data out using a ToArray on your IQueryable object. That result will be serializable over WCF.

Hope this helps

Shiraz